# Verifying validity of correctness statement using assertions

Tags: solution-verification

I need to verify the validity of this correctness statement by adding any intermediate assertions and inferencing , however I have never seen a statement where the last assertion is the same as the first, so am just a little lost on where to go.

ASSERT( x == y*(y+1)/2 )

y = y + 1;

x = x + y;

ASSERT( x == y*(y+1)/2 )

Comment: This looks like proving by induction that $\sum_{i=1}^n i=\frac{n(n+1)}2$

Comment: "I have never seen a statement where the last assertion is the same as the first": this is an *invariant*, they are ubiquitous.

Answer (score 2):

This is true. Going up with the substitution rule, we have

```
ASSERT( x + y + 1 == (y + 1) * (y + 2) / 2 )   
y = y + 1;
ASSERT( x + y == y * (y + 1) / 2 )
x = x + y;
ASSERT( x == y * (y + 1) / 2 ).
```

And obviously, `x + y + 1 == (y + 1) * (y + 2) / 2` is equivalent to `x == (y + 1) * y / 2`.